# Webview is blank or loading same page for different urls

Tags: java, android

A search api is returning me some meta data i.e a url "eventURL" and trackbackurl i.e "trackBack". I am placing the data in the listview, each row containing some data and a unique url and trackback url.When user taps on the row in the listview, a alert dialog is displayed presenting user 2 options. Clicking on option 1 should launch trackback url in a webview while clicking on second opion should launch eventURL in a webview.I have created a WebViewActivity for it,Problem is that my webview is always blank.

**Main Activity**

```
package my.stayactive.plan;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import my.stayactive.plan.ActiveHelper.ApiException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class StayActiveActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    //private EditText m_search_text;
    protected EditText m_zip;
    private ListView m_search_results;
    private Button m_search_btn;
    private JSONArray m_results; 
    private LayoutInflater m_inflater;
    private InputMethodManager m_ctrl;
    private Spinner m_radius;
    private Spinner m_activity_selector;
    public static int radius = 0;
    public static String activities;
    public String url;
    public String trackBack;
    public static String assetId;


    static final private int EXIT_ID = Menu.FIRST;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       // m_search_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        m_zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);
        m_search_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
       // m_searchm_results = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lview);
        m_search_btn .setOnClickListener(go_handler);

        m_ctrl = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
        addListenerOnSpinner1ItemSelection();

      m_search_results = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lview);
      m_search_results.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        m_radius = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        m_radius.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
      }

    public void addListenerOnSpinner1ItemSelection(){
        m_activity_selector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        m_activity_selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ActivitySelectedListener());
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, EXIT_ID, 0, R.string.exit);
        return true;
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case EXIT_ID:
            finish();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }



    OnClickListener go_handler = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //m_ctrl.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_search_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
            m_ctrl.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_zip.getWindowToken(), 0);

            //String searchText = Uri.encode(m_search_text.getText().toString());
            String zip = Uri.encode(m_zip.getText().toString());

            new SearchTask().execute("?k=Fall+Classic" + "&m=meta:channel=" + activities + "&l="+ zip + "&r=" + radius);
            // Show a toast showing the search text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.search_msg) + " " + 
                    activities, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(StayActiveActivity.this,"","Please Wait...");

                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    String result = ActiveHelper.download(params [0]);
                    return result;
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("alatta", "Problem making search request");
                }
                return "";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                dialog.hide();
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                    m_results = obj.getJSONArray("_results");
                    if (m_results == null || m_results.length() == 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No Results found for " + activities, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else
                        m_search_results.setAdapter(new JSONAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    private class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public JSONAdapter(Context c){

        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
        return  m_results.length();
            }

        public Object getItem(int arg0){
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int pos){
            return pos;

        }

        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View tv;
            TextView t;

            if (convertView == null)
                tv = m_inflater.inflate (R.layout.item, parent, false);
            else
                tv = convertView;
            try {
                /* For each entry in the ListView, we need to populate 
                 * its text and timestamp */
                t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.text);
                JSONObject obj = m_results.getJSONObject(pos);

                t.setText (obj.getString("title").replaceAll("</?(?i:<|>|...|&quot|&amp|;|)(.|\n)*?>", ""));
                        //("\\<.*?\\>", ""))

                t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
                JSONObject meta = obj.getJSONObject("meta");
              //  url = meta.getString("eventURL");
                trackBack = obj.getString("url");
                assetId = meta.getString("assetTypeId");
                //String eventDate = meta.getString("startDate");
                Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                long dateNow = currentDate.getTimeInMillis();


               String eventDate = meta.getString("startDate");
               String endDate = meta.getString("endDate");
               SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
               Date date = null;
               Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date = formatter.parse(eventDate);
                date2 = formatter.parse(endDate);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               long modifiedDate= date.getTime();
               long modifiedEndDate = date2.getTime();



                if ( Long.valueOf(dateNow).compareTo(Long.valueOf(modifiedDate)) > 0 || Long.valueOf(dateNow).compareTo(Long.valueOf(modifiedEndDate)) > 0)

                {

                    t.setText ("Was:" + "\t"+eventDate+"\n"+"Location:" +"\t" +meta.getString("location")+"\n" + meta.getString("eventURL") +"\n"+ obj.getString("url"));

                }
                    else {
                    t.setText ("When:" + "\t"+eventDate+"\n"+"Location:" +"\t" +meta.getString("location")+"\n"+ meta.getString("eventURL") +"\n"+ obj.getString("url"));
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.e("alatta", e.getMessage());
            }
            return tv;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /*try {
        JSONObject obj = m_results.getJSONObject(position);
        JSONObject meta = obj.getJSONObject("meta");
        url = meta.getString("eventURL"); 


        //Intent intent = new Intent (StayActiveActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        //StayActiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("alatta",e.getMessage());
        }*/



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Register", "Additional Information"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please Select an Option");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (which == 0){

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent (StayActiveActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                    StayActiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);

                }

                else if ( which == 1){
                Intent intent = new Intent (StayActiveActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                StayActiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

    }}
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
package my.stayactive.plan;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class WebViewActivity extends StayActiveActivity {

            private WebView webView;

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.webview);

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                WebSettings setting = webView.getSettings();
                setting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                if (url != null && url.length()>0) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);

            }
              } 


            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't pass URL to your `WebViewActivity`. To do that:

- Before calling `startActivity()`, attach your URL to the intent with [setData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData%28android.net.Uri%29).
- In `onCreate()` of `WebViewActivity`, retrieve the URL with [getData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29), then load it.

Or search for `putExtra(...)`. You can transfer a number of data with [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

**— edited —**

Example:

To set data:

```
import android.net.Uri;

//...
Intent intent = new Intent (StayActiveActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("your-url"));
StayActiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve data:

```
//...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

    //...
    webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
}
```

Comment: Here is my new Intent : 'code'  Intent intent = new Intent (StayActiveActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
     
intent.putExtra(trackBack, true);
StayActiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent1); I made changes to WebviewActivity onCreate() String register = getIntent().getStringExtra(trackBack);
m_webView.loadUrl(register);  I am still seeing a blank webview.

Comment: Your code was wrong. Because you put a boolean (`true`). You can put a string into intent.

Comment: Can you please write an example for setData() and getData() using a string.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please have a look and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. However now I am running into second part of the problem. Clicking on all list view items loads the same url.Each list view item has different url and I want to pass that different url every time.

Comment: If you have time, I think it's worth watching this ‒ [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70), it's about an hour. I can write more but I think the video is better  :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13821/discussion-between-noble6-and-lai-vung)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your URLs are redirecting and that you aren't handling the redirects so nothing is being shown.

try adding this to your webview activity:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
});
```

Also it would be a good idea since you have an if statement in your WebView activity to log the url so that you can be certain that it is actually making it in to the activity correctly. If not the web view would never load anything.

**EDIT:** actually upon closer look it doesn't seem like you're setting the 'url' variable anywhere so it would be null, thus not calling your loadUrl method because of the if statement.

Comment: I tried this but still couldn't get it to work.I had commented out url variable which i fixed.

Comment: as @LaiVung states in his answer you are not adding the url as an extra to the intent to your webview activity. So it does not know what Url to open.